# Is Jenkins the right tool for real time streaming pipeline?

Tags: python, azure, jenkins, real-time, pipeline

Say I would like to scrape json format information from an URL which refresh every 2 minutes. I need to run my pipeline (written in Python) continuously every 2 minutes to capture them without any missing data. In this case the pipeline is real time processing.

Currently, I'm using Jenkins to run the pipeline every 2 minutes but I do not think this is a correct practice and Jenkins is meant for CI/CD pipelines. I doubt mine is CI/CD pipeline. Even though I knew there is Jenkins pipeline plugin, I still think using the plugin is conceptually incorrect.

So, what is the best data processing tools in this case? At this point, no data transformation needed. I believe in the future as the process gets more complex, transformation is required. Just FYI, the data will pump into `azure blob storage`.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is meant for CI/CD pipelines and not for scheduling jobs. So yes, you are right, Jenkins isn't the right tool for what you want to achieve.

I suppose you are using Microsoft Azure.

1. If you are using Databricks, use Spark Streaming application and crate the job. 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs
2. The other approach is to use Azure DataFactory with Scheduled Trigger for the job. As you want to run every 2 minutes, I not sure what will be the cost involved.

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of DataFactory and it is not free. Can Kafka allow me to do streaming processing as well? And what about using Azure WebJob to run the pipeline? Will using WebJob also technically wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Jenkins probably should not be used as a distributed Cron system... Let it do what it's good at - CI.

You can boot any VM and create a Cron script or you can use a scheduler like Airflow

FWIW, "every 2 minutes" is not "real time"

> Just FYI, the data will pump into azure blob storage.

If you are set on using Kafka (via Event Hub), you could use Kafka Connect to scrape the site, send data into a Kafka topic, then use a sink connector to send data to WASB